# How can I allow Chinese characters in C++ input?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream, cjk

I've been trying to take Chinese (simplified) inputs through both the `iostream` in Visual Studio 2019. When I input an English word, it works fine. To make sure that the console is printing correctly, I changed the console font to something compatible with Chinese characters. Printing characters doesn't appear to be much of an issue as of yet, but inputting characters is causing me some trouble.

I tried a couple of 'fixes' found in other posts such as `setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8")` or `wcin.imbue(locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"))` or `SetConsoleCP(UTF8)`, and variants of those functions. While trying to debug, I found that the value of `b = L""`; the characters that I typed in were completely ignored.

However, when I read input from the file, it appears to be functioning; I can parse, manipulate, and print files properly.

```cpp
void prepare() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Change font to something compatible with chinese
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
    fontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(fontInfo);
    fontInfo.FontFamily = 54;
    fontInfo.FontWeight = 300;
    fontInfo.nFont = 0;
    const wchar_t myFont[] = L"KaiTi";
    fontInfo.dwFontSize = { 9, 30 };
    copy(myFont, myFont + (sizeof(myFont) / sizeof(wchar_t)), fontInfo.FaceName);

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, false, &fontInfo);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8");

    //wcin.imbue(locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));
    //wcout.imbue(locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));
}
```

Simplified sample code:

```cpp
#define _UNICODE

int main() {
    prepare(); // Prepare console to output Chinese characters properly

    wcin.imbue(locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));
    wcout.imbue(locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));

    wstring a = L"你好";
    wcout << a; // Prints and displays properly

    wstring b;
    wcin >> b; // "你好"
    wcout << b; // Nothing prints

    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: If your setup is using utf-8, do you know if the input is in unicode, DBCS or MBCS?  What kind of console are you running this from?  Has the character set on the console been modified to display Chinese using the KaiTi font?

Comment: @cup I think I set the input to be in Unicode and I'm running it from the default console output for Visual Studio 2019. The console is modified to display Chinese using the KaiTi font; if I have the unicode or character, I'm able to print it in the console. I just can't input anything properly other than English characters.

Comment: Have you tried the chinese/japanese ime?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/installing-and-using-input-method-editors

Comment: I have. I'm able to type chinese into the console, it's just that when I'm reading `wcin >> b`, the wrong value (rather, no value at all) is stored. This is only the case with CJK characters however.

Comment: Possibly reading in as MBCS with leading 00.  Stop in debugger and check what data you are getting in b.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. When I'm looking at the value, it's `L""`. When looking at the memory and byte it's simply "00".